# Bash arrays - not working

Tags: bash, array

Doing some formatting fun, playing with xargs and how it passes data to scripts etc, and I'm having a little trouble with creating an array.

```
alias lstest='ls | xargs --delimiter="\n" ~/.config/lsdif_color.sh'

for fileLine in "$@"
do
    if [[ $fileLine == total* ]]; then echo $fileLine;
    else 
        cols=($fileLine);
        echo ${#cols}, $l
        echo ${cols[0]}
        echo ${cols[$(( ${#cols}-1 ))]}
    fi;
done
```

So, this works fine.  The "cols" array shows the right length and it outputs the first and last element perfectly.

Now for the problem:

```
...
else
  # Method 1
  declare -a cw=(11 2 8 7 6 5 4 3 6 0);
  echo ${#cw}

  # Method 2
  widths=($(11 2 8 7 6 5 4 3 6 0));
  echo ${#widths}

  #Method 3
  cws[0]="11"
  cws[1]="2"
  cws[3]="8"
  cws[4]="7"
  cws[5]="6"
  cws[6]="5"
  cws[7]="4"
  cws[8]="3"
  cws[9]="6"
  cws[10]="0"

  echo ${#cws}

fi;
```

in all three method's of attempting to define these arrays, the echoed length is always 2.  Not 10.
The Cols array from above lists 10 elements, but attempting to create an array of numbers fails, even when i'm letting them be strings.

Why?

Thanks
Jaeden "Sifo Dyas" al'Raec Ruiner

Comment: I have successfully used `declare -a myarray; myarray+=("val1"); myarray+=("val2")` etc.

Comment: `${cols[-1]}` will also get you the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use:

```
echo {#cws[@]}
```

- `{#cws}` is normally used to return a string's length
- the `[@]` is important, because without this, the value of `$cws` is not the whole array, it instead defaults to first element of array's value, aka `$cws[0]`

For example on our command prompt we can do a simple three-element array similar to yours:

```
$ cws[0]="11"; cws[1]="2"; cws[3]="8"
```

Now look what happens when we refer to just `$cws`:

```
$ echo $cws
11
```

So, when using bash expansion to determine length of something, `{#` ... `}`, without the `[@]`, you write `${#cws}`, `$cws` is `11`, so you are asking bash "what is the length of 11"? and of course bash looks at the string `11` which has two characters, so Bash says `Oh it is 2":

```
$ echo ${#cws}
2
```

So, that is why to specify you meant the length of the array, remember the `[@]`:

```
$ echo ${#cws[@]}
3
```

Comment: I am an idiot, or just code blind.  I was sure I had put the @ in the string but obviously I hadn't.  the joys of teaching oneself a new language.  Like all those times in C we forgot == instead of just =.  Thanks for the pointer. :) - J"SD"a'RR

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how the arrays are referenced.  To begin:

```
$ declare -a cw=(11 2 8 7 6 5 4 3 6 0)
```

Now, let's look at the length two different ways:

```
$ echo ${#cw}
2
$ echo ${#cw[@]}
10
```

The first method is returning the length of the element of indice 0 (in this case it also happens to be first element of `cw`).  The second method, by contrast, is returning the number of elements in the array.

#### More

In the question, there is the code:

```
widths=($(11 2 8 7 6 5 4 3 6 0));
```

This code tries to execute a command called `11` with arguments `2 8 7 6 5 4 3 6 0`.  The result depends on whether there is a command called `11`.  If there isn't, you will see:

```
bash: 11: command not found
```